# win32:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)d

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt4, qt5

While studying the [Plug & Paint Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-example.html) I got stuck at the project file, more specifically at the following:

```
LIBS           = -Lplugins -lpnp_basictools

if(!debug_and_release|build_pass):CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
   mac:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)_debug
   win32:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)d
}
```

What this peace of code does? What's `$$member(LIBS, 0)`?

Since I'm on Windows, just doing

```
if(!debug_and_release|build_pass):CONFIG(debug, debug|release) 
   win32:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)d
```

seems to work also.

Comment: If I had to guess, `LIBS` is a variable that refers to a space-separated list (likely of library file names), and `$$member(LIBS, 0)` retrieves the first element of that list.

Comment: It seems the overall result is to append `d` to the file name in debug mode. Considering your comment, the `if` statement should be added after every `LIBS` line, if I understand correctly.