# lib (release) or libd (debug), can Qt resolve this for me?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

In the [Plug & Paint Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-example.html#the-plugin-interfaces) the [.pro](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-plugandpaint-pro.html) presents the following:

```
LIBS           = -Lplugins -lpnp_basictools

if(!debug_and_release|build_pass):CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
   mac:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)_debug
   win32:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)d
}
```

Which, for that particular case, appends a `d` to the lib name in debug mode, `pnp_basictools` becomes `pnp_basictoolsd`. But it doesn't scale well, i.e.:

```
LIBS           = -Lplugins -lplugin_1 -lplugin_2 -lplugin_3

if(!debug_and_release|build_pass):CONFIG(debug, debug|release)
   win32:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)d
```

Seems not to append `d` to `plugin_2` and `plugin_3`.

So, may I ask for another method to add the `d` to the lib name in debug mode?

The issue was also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238090/win32libs-memberlibs-0-memberlibs-1d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$$member(X, pos)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#member-variablename-position) returns the item at the position `pos` of the list variable `X`. So, the code you found only handles 2 of the elements of that list (0 => `-Lplugins` and 1 => `-lpnp_basictools`).

There is a [for loop](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#for-iterate-list) that could help you handle all the elements of the list, but instead you can "simply" use a regular expression with the [~= operator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#replacing-values) :

```
win32:LIBS ~= s/-l(.*)/-l\1d/g
```

Comment: Interesting things. Please could you provide more info about this regular expression?