# qmake run command only in debug mode, how?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt4, qt5

This is kind of a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253715/lib-release-or-libd-debug-can-qt-resolv-this-for-me). I want to run

```
win32:LIBS ~= s/-l(.*)/-l\1d/g
```

only for debug builds, since the idea is to appen `d` to lib names in debug mode.

I tried

```
win32:debug:LIBS ~= s/-l(.*)/-l\1d/g
```

But so it also executes in release mode.

Comment: CONFIG(debug, debug|release):win32:LIBS ~= s/-l(.*)/-l\1d/g

Comment: Would you mind to explain what the `win32:debug:LIBS ~= s/-l(.*)/-l\1d/g` does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Qt Creator's target (debug/release) (Visual Studio)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046181/how-to-detect-qt-creators-target-debug-release-visual-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `CONFIG(debug, debug|release)` instead of a simple test for presence of `debug`. The `CONFIG` variable is special, in that it can have multiple `debug` and `release` entries in it, but only the **last one counts**.

So, even in release mode, your CONFIG might look like `something, debug, something, release`: the `release` "wins" since it's the last, but the scope test doesn't know that.

It's a quirk of qmake. It is even documented, if you know where to look first :/

> As the order of values is important in CONFIG variables (that is, the last one set will be considered the active config for mutually exclusive values) a second parameter can be used to specify a set of values to consider. For example:

Comment: I confess I didn't fully understand the CONFIG logic. May I use CONFIG(debug, debug|release) multiple times in the project file?

Comment: @KcFnMi Sure, it's a test. It's like a const method: it doesn't modify any state.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how I do it normally:

```
 CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    unix:  TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,d)
    win32: TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,d)
 }
```

platform is present because initially I thought to use different conventions for different platforms and giving here just as an example

you can add this rule right after you set a target name for libs/apps

normal layout have this rule in the .pro file for generation your library and something like:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    unix:   LIBS += -L../libs -L../../libs -lyourlibnamed
    win32: LIBS += -L../libs -L../../libs -lyourlibnamed    
} else {
    unix:   LIBS += -L../libs -L../../libs -lyourlibname
    win32: LIBS += -L../libs -L../../libs -lyourlibname 
}
```

in a .pri file